# Is there a way in Rails (6.1) to check if the application is deployed or running locally without a request object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a `request` (e.g. in a controller action), I can check if the app is running locally with `request.local?`. Is there a nice way to check if I don't?

I can just check `Rails.env` since in our case `production` and `staging` environments are deployed and `test` and `development` are not, but wanted to ask in case there is a general approach.

Comment: Define "running locally". An application deployed to production might still get request from the same server and have requests considered local. An application running on your machine in development, can still receive requests remotely (tunneling or same network for example).

Comment: Why do you need anything other than `Rails.env` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46786 (merged, but [not present in the current version 7.0.4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.2/activesupport/lib/active_support/environment_inquirer.rb); probably will be released in 7.1) adds `Rails.env.local?` which effectively just returns `Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?` (except the result is cached).